# Detour recast tileLayer what is it about

Tags: c++, navigation, game-engine, navmesh

I would like to ask how **tileLayers** in detour work.

Can i layer any 2 tiles resulting in "cuts" being merged into bigger holes and in what manner, are there any limitations? How many of these layers can i have and how they interact when navigating. Can i have for example basic always unchanged layer with whole map and then multiple layers with user placed geometry etc...

I'am talking about **dtNavMeshCreateParams::tileLayer** from **original lib**. There is some implementation using it in TempObstackes example. But it is not well explained (it has many custom things inside but i'am interested only in function of those layers)

Thank you in advance, i cant find much info about this online so any help would really be appreceated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So actually i finally (many hours) found my answer to what these layers are used for:

http://digestingduck.blogspot.com/2011/02/heightfield-layer-portals.html

(btw this seems to be blog of navmesh lib author, enjoy)